# Create method with refactor shortcut, is there a way to chose between partial or non partial target?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, refactoring, partial-classes, automated-refactoring

So basically, I have a tool that I designed, that generates some code based on the model, and pastes this code automatically inside the .partial classes, on this approach, .partial is used for generated code, and his normal class is used for my manual code, this way I don´t loss my code everytime is auto-generated.

The problem is, in previous versions of visual studio, when you pressed CTRL+(dot) to refactor and create new methods, it automatically created this inside the regular file, not the partial. Knowing this I designed my tool to write auto-generated code on the partial.

Now i´m using Visual studio 15 and above, and it seems this changed, refactors are created into .partial files, making my approach annoying... I need constantly to move generated method.

is there a way to configure where to place this refactored methods?

Comment: In addition, I saw that sometimes it automatically creates method in partial, and sometimes in regular, not sure logic involved inside this feature, but still... anoying.